# get_center ignoring submobjects

Tags: python, manim

If I create a `Dot` and add (as a submobject) a label (`Text` mobject) above the dot and then call the `get_center` function, the center of the dot is moved because the function uses the submobjects to calculate the center of the mobject.

```
>>> v = Dot()
>>> v.get_center()
array([0., 0., 0.])
>>> v.add(Text('a').move_to(UP))
Dot
>>> v.get_center()
array([0. , 0.55121094, 0. ])
```

How can I get the center of the dot ignoring the submobjects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit clunky, but it does what you are asking for:

```py
>>> VMobject().set_points(v.points).get_center()
array([0., 0., 0.])
```